# How to draw this line in Activity?

Tags: android

i composed this code to animate a drawing line out of multiple examples i found here on stack:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new DrawLine(this));
}

private static class DrawLine extends View {

    public DrawLine(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
    }


    private int startX = 0;
    private int startY = 0;

    private int endX = 0;
    private int endY = 0;

    private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG) {
        {
            setDither(true);
            setColor(Color.RED);
            setStrokeWidth(40);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY, paint);

        if (endX != 300 && endY != 300) {
            endY++;
            endX++;

            postInvalidateDelayed(0); //
        }
    }

}
}
```

My question is, how can i draw this line across my MainActivity xml instead of setting the contentView with the DrawLine class? Also, is there any way to make the line draw quicker?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not working because endX and endY gets increments only once. Try giving direct values and check if it works

Comment: It is working, but what i want to do is draw the line inside my activity :D

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but this code is in kotlin . I don't know java .

```
var delay=0
var startX=0
var startY=0
var xgap=5
var ygap=5
for (i in 1..50){
            delay+=3
            handler.postDelayed(Runnable {
                canvas.drawLine(
                        startX,
                        startY,
                        stopX,
                        stopY,
                        paint)
                startX=stopX
                startY=stopY
                stopX+=xgap
                stopY+=ygap


            },delay)
```

You will get the idea. Increment a delay  and location each time
I have done this in my app and it is working

Edit: you can convert this code to java in android studio itself